# ¿Puede el código fuente revelado por scrapy ser diferente al de la página?

Tags: scrapy

Non entiendo porqué, con scrapy, tengo un codigo fuente differente con el de la url https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume En efecto, aqui esta el output de scrapy:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\scrapy-scraper>scrapy shell https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.
9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform
 Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 23c7a4cba0ad587c
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-02-23 12:48:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.nordstrom.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-02-23 12:48:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x000002A56E53F700>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x000002A56E53FD30>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x2a56ed171c0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> response.css('head')
[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::head' data='<head>\n  <title></title>\n  <style>\n  ...'>]
```

Pueden ver aqui `[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::head' data='<head>\n  <title></title>\n  <style>\n  ...'>]` que es differente del codigo fuente:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" >
    <head>
        <title data-react-helmet="true">Women&#x27;s Perfume &amp; Fragrances | Nordstrom</title>
        <meta data-react-helmet="true" charset="UTF-8"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="viewport" content="width=980"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="description" content="Free shipping and returns on women&#x27;s perfume and fragrances at Nordstrom.com. Find perfume, eau de toilette, and eau de parfum from top brands."/><meta data-react-helmet="true" name="keywords" content=""/><meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:title" content="Women&#x27;s Perfume &amp; Fragrances | Nordstrom"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:description" content="Free shipping and returns on women&#x27;s perfume and fragrances at Nordstrom.com. Find perfume, eau de toilette, and eau de parfum from top brands."/><meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:url" content="https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:site_name" content="Nordstrom"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:type" content="website"/><meta data-react-helmet="true" id="page-team" property="page-team" content="sbn"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="143447719050737" />
```

En title deberia haber `Women&#x27;s Perfume &amp; Fragrances | Nordstrom`

Tambien lo intenté con:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume")
time.sleep(30)
```

Pero detecta que utiliso chrome y me envia hasta una pagina de invitacion solo para empressas.

Comment: Si te descargas la pagina con wget lo verás. Tienen una función javascript que carga el contenido dinámicamente mediante ajax pasandole parametros a otra parte, no son páginas estáticas por asi decirlo. Su código javascript es de una 6000 lineas si lo pasas por el tidy, y tambien contiene partes que parecen en base64 o algo similar, donde quizas alli se encuentre la información que buscas

Comment: No es base64, sera algo que han encriptado con todo ese codigo pues.

Comment: Haa, que lastima @masterguru Y hay cualquier posibilidad para obtener esta información? Mi objetivo es hacer un scraper recursivo que visite las páginas de los perfumes. Y como utilisas wget ? `wget https://www.nordstrom.com/browse/beauty/fragrance/perfume` ?

Comment: No se como obtener la información, la verdad, supongo que buscando algun scrapper que permita engañar a la web para que se ejecute su javascript que crea los elementos que faltan o cargando ese ajax que aparece por ahi. Creo que hay varios para python, pero lo desconozco, lo siento. En cuanto a wget, si tal cual lo has escrito te descarga un archivo denominado **perfume** en el directorio desde donde lo estes ejecutando (en un terminal, claro)

Comment: Necesitas esperar a que se ejecute el javascript. Lo he hecho varias veces con Selenium pero con Scrapy nunca lo he intentado, así que no sé si es posible.

Comment: En este caso @ÁlvaroMondéjar seria interesado para ver como lo hice !

Comment: Por desgracia me dice parece que detecta que soy utilisando Selenium. Obtengo : "`To keep our site secure, we don’t allow unidentified, automated traffic. If you’d like access to our data via automation apply to join the Nordstrom Affiliate Network`"

Comment: ¿y como continua la frase?  quizas te dan alguna solucion... esa frase no esta terminada